# Animation with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I want to hav this kind of animation in my app, a case where an arrow shape  such that when clicked it transforms into a mark.

This is what i have at present using the code below

[image: present work]

```
func handleTransform(){

    let arrowPath = UIBezierPath()
    arrowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 25, y: 75))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 25, y: 75))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 25, y: 45))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 25, y: 35))
    arrowPath.close()

    let progressLines = CAShapeLayer()
    progressLines.path = arrowPath.cgPath
    progressLines.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    progressLines.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLines.lineWidth = 10.0
    progressLines.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(progressLines)

    let animateStrokeEnd = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animateStrokeEnd.duration = 3.0
    animateStrokeEnd.fromValue = 0.0
    animateStrokeEnd.toValue = 1.0

    progressLines.add(animateStrokeEnd, forKey: "animate stroke end animation")

}
```

the flow is illustrated in the images bellow

**On click of this image**
[image: arrow icon]

**It transform to this image**
[image: Mark icon]

Comment: Have you tried simple 'image switch' after the button was clicked ?

Comment: @EricAya i have added the code of what i tried doing, got no where finding solution

Comment: @Vexy i don't think switching images will work, cus there's a stroke in the second image longer than the first

Comment: @SimpiMind Thank you for editing your question with your attempt. This question will get much better attention now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able t solve, i did a switch image with animation